# I received GPG error while using sudo apt update in Pop!_OS 22.04

Tags: apt, repository

I ran `sudo apt update` and it shows this:

> An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used.
> GPG error: https://repo.waydro.id jammy InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 0E406D181DCEE19C

Comment: I asked same question yesterday but it was not clear , so I reposted the question and please tell the solution if anyone knows

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you're missing the GPG signing key for the Waydroid repo.

You can add the key by running the following command:

```
curl --progress-bar --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -Sf https://repo.waydro.id/waydroid.gpg --output /usr/share/keyrings/waydroid.gpg
```

Then, just run `sudo apt update` again and it should work.

If it doesn't work, then check the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list` OR `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/waydroid.list` if it exists. Make sure it contains the following:

```
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/waydroid.gpg] https://repo.waydro.id/ jammy main
```